# Name based virtual hosts serve the same SSL site

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, vhosts

On my server I have the following vhost definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
  ServerAdmin admin@mysiste.com
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias www.mysite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/current/public
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.key/myserver.key
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/mysite_com.crt
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/mysite_com.ca-bundle
  <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/current/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The site itself works fine, the problem is that if I try any other site (vhost) hosted on the same server with https and skip the warning I get served mysite.com. This wouldn't be a problem for the casual user but I noticed Google tried and actually indexed a ton of URLs on my "other" sites via https which were actually pages from mysite.com and I'm afraid I'll get penalized for duplicate content.

How do I deny the other sites to be served via https?

Comment: I just realized... If any of the mods consider that this doesn't belong here, please move it to the correct SE site. However there are other Apache config related questions around on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. For further reference this is Ubuntu 12.04.

In `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` added the following to the `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` section:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

As per the instructions in the above file, modified in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` from `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

Then:

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Done.